# Probability question - Normal and Uniform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

In a factory there are $2$ machines that create tubes (They are independent from each other)  Length of the tubes of machine A is distributed normally with an expectancy of $101$ cm. and a Variance of $102$.  ($\mu = 101, V[A]=102$)
The tubes of the second machine is distributed uniformly $U(85, 115)$
A proper length of a tube is $[90,110]$, it is known that $90\%$ of all the tubes are fine.

1. What is the percentage of the tubes created in Machine A ?

I've tried to solve it, but I get a weird answer:

$X \sim N(101, \sqrt{102})$  - Machine A (and $\sqrt{102}$ because $\sigma = \sqrt{\mathbb{V}[X]}$ )
$Y \sim \text{Uniform}(85,115)$  - Machine B

So we can build this equation:
$a \cdot \mathbb{P}(90 \leq X \leq 110) + (1-a) \cdot \mathbb{P}(90 \leq Y \leq 110) = 0.9$

Where $a$ is the percentage of all the tubes created at machine A (and thus $1-a$ is the percentage of machine B , however I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it0

I calculate $\mathbb{P}(90 \leq X \leq 110) = P(Z \leq 0.89) - P(Z \leq -1.09) = 0.6754$

And:

$\mathbb{P}(90 \leq Y \leq 110) = \frac{1}{115-85} \cdot (110-90) = \frac{2}{3}$

And I get:

$a \cdot 0.6754 + (1-a) \cdot \frac{2}{3} = 0.9$
But $a = 26.7$  which is greater than $1$. I am very confused what I did wrong here.

What I think the mistake is: I am not sure if the information that the machines are independent from each other mean that: $P_{A} + P_{B} = 1$
meaning, I am not sure that the percentage machine A creates + percentage of machine B creates = $1$ , but it seemed logical, no?
What is the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- what is requested is a conditional probability.

Then to get a you have to solve

$$\frac{0.6755\cdot a}{  0.6755\cdot a +(1-a)\cdot \frac{2}{3}}=0.9$$

leading to $a\approx 0.899$

I want to underline that "Variant" in Statistics has no a nice meaning.

We have "variance" and "standard deviation".

If you 102 is expressed in cm cannot be a variance but a standard deviation....so verify what your data mean....anyway the procedure does not change.

Comment: The standard deviation is $\sigma = \sqrt{102}$ , but why do we need conditional probability?

Comment: @StackOMeow :   so $\sigma^2$ cannot be expressed in cm.... do you agree?

Comment: I don't think it matters so much doesn't it? ;) and why is it a conditional probability?

Comment: @StackOMeow : the conditional probability come out directly by the question: given that the "good tubes" are 90% calculate the % of the production of the two lines

Comment: @StackOMeow : my observation about the unit measure does not affect the procedure or the result...it was only an observation...now, known that you mean $\sigma^2=102$ I amendend you text

Comment: But conditional probability is of form: $P(A | B )$ so $B=$ given that 90% are fine. what is the $A$ here?

Comment: The text is: "It is known that 90% of the tubes are fine". That means that $P(A|B)=0.9$. If the two % of fine tube are both around 67% their linear combination cannot be 90%. The resutl of B is a % that goes from 67.55 through 66.67%

Comment: I don't think I got that yet